# Why are area queries in my own Overpass server returning different results from the official server?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Here's my query to collect all of the States within the US:

```
[out:json];
area['admin_level'='2']['name'='United States'];
(relation['admin_level'='4'](area););
out tags;
```

My Overpass server returns [Baja California](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2589601) in the results for this query, even though this state is in Mexico. [Overpass Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/LOo) correctly excludes this from the results.

Similarly, my query to collect all of the cities within Indiana returns Chicago in the results (while the Overpass Turbo only includes East Chicago & New Chicago):

```
[timeout:900][out:json];
area['ISO3166-2'~'^US']['admin_level'='4']['name'='Indiana'];
(relation['admin_level'~'8'](area););
out tags;
```

I'm using the [wiktorn/overpass-api](https://hub.docker.com/r/wiktorn/overpass-api) Docker image that I started it with:

```
docker run \
  -e OVERPASS_META=yes \
  -e OVERPASS_MODE=clone \
  -e OVERPASS_DIFF_URL=https://planet.openstreetmap.org/replication/minute/ \
  -v /home/ubuntu/overpass_clone_db/:/db \
  -p 80:80 \
  -i -t \
  --name overpass_world \
  wiktorn/overpass-api
```

Is there something that I can do to correct these results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was something wrong with my initial attempt at using the Docker image. I deleted my container and retried the process - everything worked great.

Also, installing Overpass directly onto a server worked great too.